# Themeing Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, themes

I have tried using [Eclipse E4](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4) on Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) and it worked well. I have tried using `Dark Theme` provided by Github on this [link](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes) but only missed darkening minimized views and also the menubar. Also, I've tried using [Eclipse Color Theme](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) to provide a `Sublime Text` look on my editors. But that is not the real question.

Though Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) supports themeing, is there a way we could install a software similar to [Eclipse E4](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4) on Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo)? (With the exception of [Eclipse Color Theme](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this plugin is great:
https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes (for eclipse 4.2+)

After install go to *Pereferences → General → Appearance* and Choose *Jeeeyul's Themes* in the Pulldown.

Then go to *Pereferences → General → Appearance → Chrome Theme* and adjust for your needs.

In the upper right corner of this Panel, you can also coose " Presets", but there are no nice one for dark-Theme, so i had made my own.

There seems no import and export, but if you want to try my, copy this file to
./configuration/net.jeeeyul.eclipse.themes/user-presets.xml

And Choose it as dev_pool in 'User's presets'

File: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60080800/user-presets.xml

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: jeeyul theme is for eclipse 4.2+. CSS Theme is only supported in 4.2+. not for indigo